# Is there a constant time solution to the safe queens problem?(python)

Tags: python, big-o

I'm working on the safe queens problem and I'm curious if there is a constant time solution to the question.

### Safe Queens

In chess the queen is the most powerful piece, as it can move any number of unoccupied squares in a straight line along columns (called "files"), rows (called "ranks"), and diagonals. It is, however, possible to place 8 queens on a board such that none are threatening another.

In this challenge we read an input of 8 positions in standard algebraic notation (files "a" to "h" and ranks "1" to "8"). Our goal is to determine, using the safe_queens function, if all of the queens are safe from each other – that is, none of them should share a file, rank, or diagonal. If they are all safe, the function should print 'YES', otherwise it should print 'NO'.

Example:
Input:
a5
b3
c1
d7
e2
f8
g6
h4

(example input positions shown on board below)

Output:
YES

This example outputs 'YES' because no queens share a file, rank, or diagonal. If the a5 were an a4 it would output 'NO' because the leftmost two queens would be on the same diagonal.

I believe that you could transform the solution be into constant time by keeping track of visited squares and checking for inference for the diagonals, but I'm not 100% sure.

```
def safe_queens():
  positions = [input() for _ in range(8)]

  # if there isn't exactly one queen per file and per rank then return 'NO'
  if (len({i[0] for i in positions}) != 8) or (
      len({i[1] for i in positions}) != 8):
       return 'NO'

  # to check diagonals compare difference between each queen combinations
  # rank values and file values, adjust for both diagonal directions by 
  # using abs()
  for p in range(8):
    for q in range(p+1, 8):
      if (abs(ord(positions[p][0]) - ord(positions[q][0]))) == (
          abs(int(positions[p][1]) - int(positions[q][1]))):
        return 'NO'
  return 'YES'
```

Link to colab notebook with the problem description and my soluion: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1sJN6KnQ0yN-E_Uj6fAgQCNdOO7rcif8G

The solution above is O(n^2), but I'm looking for a constant time solution. Thanks!

Comment: Your suggestion that your code execution time is O(n^2) only matters if n changes - but n is constant 8 so the execution time is basically constant.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the same for the diagonals as you do for the files and ranks: make a set of all diagonal numbers and check for the length of the set. You can number the diagonals this way:

```
diagonals1 = {ord(position[0]) - int(position[1]) for position in positions}
if len(diagonals1) < 8:
    return 'NO'

diagonals2 = {ord(position[0]) + int(position[1]) for position in positions}
if len(diagonals2) < 8:
    return 'NO'
```